# Do PayPal smart buttons require an intent?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I recently created some buttons and copied the code directly from their website. I copied and pasted exactly what they gave me. However, when I checked this morning I noticed that there was a warning in the console. When I checked their documentation I saw that leaving the "intent" parameter empty defaulted to "capture". Now, the buttons give me the following warning: "Expected intent=subscription to be passed to SDK, but got intent=capture". I don't see "subscription" as an intent value mentioned in their documentation. Has anyone experienced this problem?

Below is the warning given in the console:

```
smart_button_validation_error_expected_intent_subscription
Expected intent=subscription to be passed to SDK, but got intent=capture
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning was added recently; that intent=subscription query string parameter will be required in some future time.

The future requirement hasn't made its way into the documentation yet, but I expect you'll see it there soon.

Basically, add intent=subscription to your SDK line now when using subscriptions for them to be future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

This hardly seems like a future proofing... What about if I want to use both `createOrder` and `createSubscription` with the same sdk? Adding `intent=subscription` breaks `createOrder`. What would be a proper solution in this case?

Comment: You can’t even use both createSubscription and createOrder in one script. As with all PayPal APIs, dev UX is horrible.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue with a solution suggested here https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1463#issuecomment-729241771

Still this feels really strange and I don't really understand why this has to be so rigid.

Comment: Yeah, I luckily know which version I need to load, so it’s not a problem for me. Just annoying.

Comment: If I were to be honest, I am thinking of dropping paypal as their webhooks are not working as they should and are causing endless warnings.